# PHP mail blank variables

Tags: php

I am trying to get my php validate that the user has put in the info that is needed.

I want to make sure that the person has put in there name and email.  When I put just:

```
if(empty($name){
  blah blah
}
```

it gives the error but it still process the email. When I put:

```
if(empty($name){
  blah blah
}else{
  blah blah
}
```

I get an error saying: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/dreamcpu/public_html/insert.php on line 34`.

Here is my php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","blah","blah");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 
mysql_select_db("dreamcpu_contact_info", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO contact_us (name, email,phone_number,job_request,DateRequested)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone_number]','$_POST[job_requested]','$today')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error(). "Actual query: " . $sql);
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone_number'];
$job = $_POST['job_requested'];
if (empty($name)){
echo "The name field was blank. Please go back and fill in the required fields";
}
else
{
$to = "programmers@dreamcpu.com";
$subject = "A job have been requested";
$message = "On " . $today . " a job has been requested from " . $name . " please email them at " . $email . " or call them at " . $phone;
$headers = "From:" . $email;
mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
echo "<h3 style='display:block;'>Thank you for contacting DreamCPU. We have received   your request $_POST[name]. We will review it and contact you as soon as possible.</h3>";
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: very basic php runtime error. I recommend using an editor with line numbers and the php manual regarding basic syntax.

Comment: the thing is it worked without ; when I was processing sql connection

Comment: You're probably downvoted as a forgotten semicolon is a very basic beginner's mistake every good editor will mark and you could have found it yourself by reading your code carefully. the code shown above would not run as you'll always get a `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}'` including the line number pointing to the **next** incorrect term.

Comment: But because of that I am not allowed to ask questions and I still don't know why penalize people for that.

Comment: You'd try to solve errors yourself first instead of asking others. Make an effort!

Comment: before I ask a question I go do research I look up in google, research here, I look at other people working code and try to make it work, I go days even weeks before I ask a question. So to say make an effort without knowing makes you in the wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon:

```
mysql_close($con);
-----------------^
```

The variable inside your string should also not be relying on constants:

```
echo " ... request $_POST['name']. We will ...";
--------------------------^----^
```

You also forgot a closing bracket on this line:

```
if(empty($name)){
---------------^
  blah blah
}
```

Comment: The variable inside your string should also not be relying on constants:

`echo " ... request $_POST['name']. We will ...";
--------------------------^----^`
dont see where I wrote that and wouldn't I want to get the info from the variable maybe I'm not understanding what you mean on this

Comment: Jose Ortiz: When PHP does a lookup on `$_POST[name]`, it initially checks to see if the constant `name` has been defined so it can use its value as the key.  However, since it doesn't exist, it falls back and uses the string value of `name` (simply `"name"`).  It's bad practice to omit the quotes around `name` if it's a string and not a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Use a semicolon.

```
mysql_close($con);
```